# linux remembers passwords of deleted accounts

Tags: passwords, user-accounts, history, pam

When an account is deleted the line in /etc/security/opasswd for that account is not deleted. Intermittently, we are unable to re-create that account with error "password has been used".

- Why is the line in opasswd not deleted when the account is deleted? Is that a bug?
- Why does linux sometimes reject the password because it was used before the account was deleted?

Other than not deleting files and directories that belonged to a deleted account, why isn't everything associated with an account deleted when the account is deleted? If account johnsmith is deleted and then account johnsmith is created, why assume the two john smiths are the same? They may be two distinct persons.

Comment: Don't know the answer, but it might help to know exactly how you deleted the account - command line/GUI, etc.. This sounds like a pretty generic issue, but it might also help to know what distro and release you are using as well.